# Laravel Eloquent fail union between two relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, **users** and **projects** and another table called **users_project** used to perform many to many relation.

Users columns: id, firstname, lastname, ... (others not important for this post)

Projects columns: id, commercial, name, ... (others not important for this post)

Users_project: user_id, project_id

In my User model class I have two methods:

```
public function commercial_projects() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'commercial', 'id');
    }
```

and

```
public function assigned_projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Project',
            'users_project',
            'user_id',
            'project_id'
        );
    }
```

This methods works fine.
The first return how many projects have the user involved as commercial user
The second return how many projects are assigned to user

I want to have another method that return all project where user are involved in (commercial or assigned)

I wrote this method as follow:

```
public function projects() {

        return $this -> assigned_projects() -> union( $this->commercial_projects() );
    }
```

**But I have the error caused by pivot column added by belongsToMany relationship:**

```
"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select `projects`.*, `users_project`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `users_project`.`project_id` as `pivot_project_id` from `projects` inner join `users_project` on `projects`.`id` = `users_project`.`project_id` where `users_project`.`user_id` = 13) union (select * from `projects` where `projects`.`commercial` = 13 and `projects`.`commercial` is not null))"
```

**How can I remove pivot column from database request or find a way to fix this issue?**

Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select only projects columns of assigned_projects

```
->select("projects.*")
```

To be like this

```
return $this->assigned_projects()->select("projects.*")->union($this->commercial_projects());
```